# Сносим крышу отладчикам

Tags: ассемблер, отладка, masm32

Есть одна интересная программа, которую невозможно отладить. На высокоуровневых языках такую нельзя создать.

```
CSEG segment
org 100h

begin:
    mov sp, offset Lab_1
    mov ax, 9090h
    push ax
    int 20h

Lab_1:
    mov ah, 9
    mov dx, offset mess
    int 21h
    int 20h

mess db 'OLOLO!$'
CSEG ends
end begin
```

Было бы интересно изучить, что здесь происходит. Итак...

1) Что происходит? По умолчанию стек начинается с адресов FFFEf или FFFFh (sp указывает под дно) и растет вверх до секции машинных кодов. Командой mov sp, offset Lab_1 мы загружаем в sp число 109 - адрес первой инструкции под меткой Lab_1.

Заглянем в Hiew.

[image: hiew 1]

Девятый байт - это инструкция, на которую указывает регистр sp, а выше нее находятся два байта инструкции int 20h. Это хорошо видно в хексах, где девятый байт выделен, а левее расположена инструкция int 20h.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда мы пушим число 9090 (0x90 - кода NOP'а), байты 0x90 и 0x90 перезаписывают байты CD-20, поэтому прерывание выхода из программы затирается, и в этом месте ничего не происходит. Поэтому программа выполняется дальше, и строка выводится.

Почему отладчик работает неверно? Самый интересный вопрос. Это как-то связано с тем, что отладчики используют стек пользовательской программы (которая находится под отладчиком). Это я сам пока не могу объяснить.

Почему-то отладчик глюкнулся еще до того, как я запушил в стек нопы:

[image: afd 1]

То есть при выполнении инструкции mov ax, 9090h

[image: afd 2]

Что произошло в отладчике?

Comment: Ой, AFD! Ностальгиииия!

Comment: Заметьте, что без cli этот код небезопасен. После того, как вы выставили SP себе в код, первое же пришедшее прерывание этот код разрушит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отладчики работают за счет подмены команд в точках останова, а при пошаговом режиме каждую следующую команду на код `0xCC` так же именуемую `int 3`.
Внутри прерывания отладчик подменяет команду обратно из запомненной в своей области памяти.

На картинке 1 отладчика мы видим текущую команду `mov ax,9090`, но не надо верить глазам своим, разрушение кода уже началось, как только была выполнена `mov sp,0109`. Просто отладчик восстановил (исключительно на экране) эту команду для нас. Реально в памяти он меняет один байт на CC и потом восстанавливает так же 1 байт.

И так, вернемся на 1 команду назад, до первой картинки. Вернее на момент когда мы нажимаем кнопку 'Step'. Что бы остановится сразу после `mov sp,0109`, отладчик подменяет следующий за ней байт `B8` на `CC` и саму B8 запоминает где то у себя. Команда отрабатывает, процессор начиначинает выполнение команды `int 3`.

Как известно, команды `int` кладут в стек 6 байт для реального режима. `push flags, push cs, push ip`, и передают управление на обработчик прерывания. По окончании прерывания стек разматывается назад, происходит возврат на точку вызова прерывания. В защищенном режиме сложнее, думаю там должен быть 32 битный eip.

А теперь посмотрим внимательно на картинку 2, мы видим: по смещению, куда указывал наш SP, 0108-0107 лежит значение `7302` - это наши флаги, по смещению 0106-0105 `19F5` - это наш `CS`. Следующие байты я уже не могу интерпретировать, часть скрыл от нас отладчик, рисуя для нас `mov ax,9090`, а часть это видимо старшая часть EIP, которую мы в отладчике в принципе не видим.

Когда прерывание окончено отладчик восстанавливает 1 байт на `B8` для mov, но посмотрим на регистр AX на втором экране, там лежит `20CD`, а не `9090` как мы ожидали, это потому что mov уже был испорчен, просто отладчик этот факт от нас скрыл.

Comment: А про то, что байты int 21h затираются, я был прав? Если это так, то странно, почему можно менять память, не устанавливая на участок памяти режим записи. И является ли это подменой адреса возврата? Обычно подменой называют другое.

Comment: Первое, что делает отладчик включает режим записи. что бы ставить точки остановки. С другой стороны, если бы участок памяти был защищен, то программа бы не записала 9090 вместо int 20. А вывалилась бы по нарушению защиты, это в идеальной ОС. Но тут уже вопрос в том, как ОС под которой вы это запускаете выполняет эти файлы. судя по тому, что CS=DS=ES и т.п. это com файл, для них винда эмулирует старое DOS поведение. И как она может защитить код от записи, если DS для так собранных программ равен CS

Comment: И на самом деле я не в курсе как винда работает с exe собранными под DOS, т.е. с MZ заголовком, а не PE. Возможно там то же все сегменты памяти открыты. То что можно прочитать про процессоры - это идеал, которого можно достичь, раз современные ОС часто позволяют выполнять стек, значит они далеки от идеала :)

Comment: Я эту программу запустил под эмулятором дос.

Comment: Ну вот он и эмулирует DOS. А DOS был написан, когда защищенного режима в помине не было. там куда хочешь пиши. Ну были всякие "расширители памяти", типа emm386 или как его там, он реально держал камень в защищенном режиме, хотя все программы видели его как реальный.