# Как "за кулисами" работают современные дебагеры?

Tags: отладка, ide

Современные дебагеры обладают многими возможностями, например:

1. Можно поставить точку останова на ходу
2. Некоторые дебагеры позволяют править последующий код после останова, который на следующем шаге и будет выполнен
3. Условные точки останова

и многие другие вещи(просмотр\редактирование переменных и т п)

Как происходит вся эта магия?

Абстрактно я представляю, как это делается, но хочется подробностей.

Как я понимаю, вся магия начинается с `CreateRemoteThread` дебагером в отлаживаемом процессе.

Comment: Пишем INT 3 в точку останова, прежний байт запоминаем. Через DebugAPI система сообщает отладчику какое событие и где произошло. В этот момент отладчик может проверить условие бряка.

Comment: а что такого "магического" в просмотре и редактировании переменных ? Это всего лишь работа с оперативной памятью и интерпретация что где лежит (что видно из кода). Код это то же просто кусок памяти, который можно править (получив у ОС соответсвующие права). Самый сложный из ваших вопросов это условные точки останова. Если они есть дебагер трассирует программу по шагам, т.е. ставит точку останова сразу за текущей инструкцией, при останове проверяет условия и переносит точку останова дальше на одну инструкцию. Вам он показывает это только когда событие произошло

Comment: См. так же https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/466496/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%88%D1%83-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC/466521#466521  там про работу в реальном режиме, но в защищенном все примерно так же, только появились для простых ситуаций регистры отладки, надо получать права на доступ к памяти другого процесса и такие трюки, о котором там идет речь не будут работать, так как у отладчика свой стек,а адрес возврата пишется в сегмент состояния задачи, а не стек отлаживаемой программы

Answer (score 1):

Доброго времени суток. Поделюсь теми кусками информации, которыми владею.

1. Отладка может осуществляться на низком уровне - в системе есть прерывание, ответственное за точку останова. Отладчик позволяет вставить это прерывание в код, который уже загружен в память.
2. При этом правится машинный код, если это позволяет размер выделенной памяти. Не многие отладчики это поддерживают.
3. Прерывание может быть в условии :)
4. Просмотр и редактирование переменных - отладчик составляет таблицу соответствия адресов переменных в памяти и их идентификаторов. Не самая сложная задача.

Все это касается отладчиков низкого уровня. Интерпретируемые языки отлаживаются гораздо проще, конечно.

Comment: Современным отладчикам на платформе intel уже не приходится править код для вставки точек останова (если их немного). для этого есть специальные регистры процессора http://www.club155.ru/x86internalreg-dr

Comment: Спасибо за уточнение. Пополнил багаж знаний.)